# mysql workbench migrate database with two different names

Tags: mysql, database, migration, mysql-workbench

I'm using mysql workbench to try and migrate from 1 mysql database on my VPS to another on my DS; However the database names are different and I cannot change the database names due to restrictions.

When trying to migrate from the VPS to the DS I get an error because the two database names are different.

Is it possible in mysql workbench to set this up correctly as I can't seem to find it.

Comment: if it is a script, can you do CTRL-H (Find and Replace) on schema name ?

Comment: It's being used on a mac using their program and migration wizard

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can do it in *manual editing* step. From *view* combobox select *All Objects*, then double click on target schema name and rename it.

[image]

Comment: still you are unable to set this as an option. What if you have to migrate tens of objects?! And still this is possible only for the schema creation - with data transfer you can't ...

Comment: yes you can, just did it. Added image of the setting. Make sure to select `all objects`

Comment: Clarification: this needs to be slow double click. So not really a double click, but click, wait for about a second, and then click again. Wasn't obvious to me